# Python vs Shell: Performance for large file manipulation

Tags: python, bash, performance, csv

I have a **CSV** file with more the 1 million data with 50 columns. I need to read it line by line and to create a new CSV file with few columns.

I need to know which is faster for performing file manipulation: Python or shell script?

Comment: I would recommend you to use AWK instead of python/shell

Comment: If it's non-trivial CSV (Quoted fields with commas in them, etc.), consider `csvcut` from the `csvkit` package. (Which is written in python fwiw).

Comment: @rid While calling other tools is the usual way to work with shells, it is not mandatory. In `bash` (and even plain POSIX `sh`) you have plenty of built-ins that are capable of doing the job, albeit very slowly.

Comment: The answer depends heavily on what *"`with few columns`"* means. Please specify the exact requirements. Also, describe your csv file. Is it a simple one without quoting?

Comment: AWK in solves the case in 10 seconds. Thanks @jv96

Comment: @EaswerA.P please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Shell scripts are excellent for concise filesystem operations and scripting the combination of existing functionality in filters and command-line tools via pipes.

When your needs are greater - whether in functionality, robustness, performance, efficiency etc - then you can move to a more full-featured language, I think Python, Perl, and Ruby are awesome languages. Not only because of dynamic typing and the lack of need to be compiled, but because tools like `pandas`,`Fabric`, `Capistrano`, `Puppet`, and a lot of others which makes the life a lot easier, general-purposes programming languages. These have a rich variety of statement types, numerous built-in data structures, and no wired-in assumptions or shortcuts to speak of.

with python you can import your .txt or .csv file into a DataFrame which faster and easy to manipulate

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/PathToFile.txt', sep = ',')
```

notes :

1. By default, read_csv uses a C parser engine for performance. The C
   parser can only handle single character separators. If your CSV has
   a multi-character separator, you will need to modify your code to
   use the 'python' engine. You can also pass regular expressions: `pd.read_csv(..., sep=r'\s*\|\s*', engine='python')`
2. `UnicodeDecodeError` occurs when the data was stored in one encoding
   format but read in a different, incompatible one. Most common
   encoding schemes are 'utf-8' and 'latin-1', your data is likely to
   fit into one of these.
3. `header=False` specifies that the first row in the CSV is a data row
   rather than a header row, and the names=[...] allows you to specify
   a list of column names to assign to the DataFrame when it is
   created.

an alternative to pandas library using Python's built-in csv module:

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint
with open('foo.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = reader.next()
    column = {h:[] for h in headers}
    for row in reader:
        for h, v in zip(headers, row):
            column[h].append(v)
    pprint(column)    # Pretty printer
```

another solution you can use `csv.DictReader`:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open('foo.csv'))
dictobj = next(reader)
```

but I would recommend you to use `pandas`, for a small, targeted purposes, a dict may be faster. And if that is all you need, then use a dict, for sure! But if you need the power and luxury of a DataFrame, then a dict is no substitute. It is meaningless to compare speed if the data structure does not first satisfy your needs.